# How to sign something with dgst combined with pkcs8

Tags: openssl

I have a pkcs#8 encrypted key. I would like to sign a file using this key without having to decrypt it beforehand. What I want to achieve is to do all the process with a single openssl command.

Something like this :

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign pkcs8 -inform DER -in private.key -out 
sign_this.txt.signed sign.txt
```

This command would prompt for the password and then generate the signature.

Is it possible to nest commands with openssl? Please explain the right way to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`openssl dgst -sign` with `-keyform der` (not `-inform`) accepts only clear privatekey. However, this command can accept all 4 PEM formats for privatekey: legacy clear or encrypted, and pkcs8 clear or encrypted. For an encrypted key you do need to supply the password when it is used, of course; I assume your 'without decrypt beforehand' is not meant to exclude that.

Commandline operations `pkcs8 rsa pkey` will convert an encrypted privatekey from DER to PEM only by decrypting and then re-encrypting (both requiring the password), but you can do it directly by something like:

```
 printf '%s\n' "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----" >tempkey.pem
 openssl base64 <pk8derfile >>tempkey.pem
 printf '%s\n' "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----" >>tempkey.pem
 # variants with sed, awk, perl, etc are possible if better for you 
 # and of course change filename(s) if you like

 openssl dgst -sha256 -sign tempkey.pem <data -out signature
```

On Unix in some shells (notably bash) you can do this all-at-once by

```
 openssl dgst -sha256 -sign <(printf ... base64 ... printf ...) ...
```

I don't know if you count that as a single command or not.